# Find out field length of "%f" format in sprintf

Tags: c, floating-point, c99, printf

So deep inside a library I need a function which allocates a string, writes a provided floating point number to the string with %f format, and returns it. snprintf() returns the number of characters that would be needed, which would allow me to allocate the right size with 2 snprintf() calls. Unfortunately this is a somewhat performance-critical piece, so I'd like to avoid that as *printf() can be slow (yes, in some benchmarks it does show up at #1 on the profile).

Another way is to use some of the C99 functions to figure it out, but libm calls take a fair bit of time as well. A (very much simplified, no error handling etc.) version of my function would look something like the following

```
// Return a string containing number x in %f format with d digits after the decimal point.
char* my_function(double x, int d)
{
    int n = ceil(log10(pow(2, ilogb(x))));
    // 3 extra chars, the initial sign, the ".", and the terminating null.
    char *s = malloc(n + d + 3);
    snprintf(s, n + d+ 3, "%#-+.*f", d, x);
    return s;
}
```

A potentially even faster way would be to allocate a string which is "large enough", and then do the second snprintf call only if the unlikely happened and it turned out to be too short.

It's also possible to structure the code so that I can use stack allocation with alloca() and/or C99 VLA's, but as stack space is often quite limited I'd like to avoid blowing a lot of memory on a worst-case sized buffer.

Any better idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running in a memory constrained system? If you're not at the point where you really need to count bytes, simply determine your worst case and make all allocations this size.

Another option is to make the caller provide the buffer.

Finally, do you know if you can state that there will not be a need for more than a finite number of these values to exist at once? If so, pre-allocate the space for them and don't do the malloc() within your function. Since you say performance is critical, you should be trying to avoid malloc() as well.

Comment: I can structure the code such that I can use stack allocation (alloca()) instead, thus removing malloc performance from the equation. But in that case I'd like to avoid blowing a lot of stack space on a worst-case sized buffer. Otherwise memory isn't particularly limited.

Comment: If you're going to use a stack allocation, you cannot return your pointer to your caller -- once you return, the pointer allocated during your current stack frame is no longer valid. However, you can have the caller perform the allocation and pass the pointer into your function safely (assuming the caller does not need to send the buffer back to its own caller).

Comment: "avoid blowing a lot of stack space on a worst-case sized buffer" - the worst case for `n` with an IEEE double is 308. Normally most of those digits are meaningless due to loss of precision, of course. Your function isn't recursive, so how minuscule of a system does this need to run on, that you don't think you can use 300 bytes of stack? Even if `d` gets big, there's an upper limit to how many decimal places a double has before it terminates. It's the same as the number of bits of significand, maybe plus 1, so 50-something. That's because 1/8 only has 3 d.p, 1/16 only has 4, etc.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Actually, I'm generating several versions of this function for different argument types, including quad precision. And, even though most of the digits are meaningless (for some definition of meaningless at least), I certainly don't want the result to be truncated since I'm using %f format and truncation could thus change the magnitude of the result.

Comment: @janneb: that could explain why the code's so hot, if you're generating 5k of fairly useless decimal digits for a large quad-precision value :-(. Even so: "how minuscule of a system ... 5k of stack"?

Comment: @SteveJessop: It's a library, and I can't dictate that it must be used sensibly.  I'd like to have the common cases fast, and the "silly" ones (as in, %f format with very large values) correct. But maybe you're correct, and I shouldn't worry about a mere 5KB of extra stack usage.

Answer (score 1):

As you said in a comment [Find out field length of "%f" format in sprintf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9430415/find-out-field-length-of-f-format-in-sprintf/9432089#comment11926848_9430784) :  **I'd like to have the common cases fast, and the "silly" ones (as in, %f format with very large values) correct.**

Here is a solution:

```
char *function (double x, int d)
{
    ssize_t ret;
    size_t size = 32;
    char *buffer = malloc(size);

    ret = snprintf(buffer, size, "%#-+.*f", d, x);
    if (ret < size) {
        return buffer;
    }

    size = ret + 1;
    buffer = realloc(buffer, size); 
    snprintf(buffer, size, "%#-+.*f", d, x);

    return buffer;
}
```

32 bytes is a common size for the smallest allocation done by malloc(), requesting less doesn't give you anything.
You can tune the default size to match the common values you're going to convert.

Answer (score 0):

Did you know that common malloc() implementation can't allocate less than 32 bytes.
So you should probably not care about the exact size of your string.

If your program is time critical/or with memory constraint, use the interchange format %a (%A), the maximum length of the string would be very small (-0x1.fffffffffffffp+1023 is the minimum negative value) and use pre-allocated slot (using a dedicated slab allocator).

Comment: Yes, %a, %e, and %g formats are easy cake. But we need to support %f as well, and that's a PITA. :-/

Comment: Don't compare %e, %g and %a: using %a, printf() doesn't have to do much of computation, it's simpler, faster, and space efficient compared to %e, %g. ... but could be hard to read for untrained eyes.

Comment: I'm comparing them in the sense that it's easy to know upfront how much space one needs to allocate. I'm certainly aware that %a is much faster to format than %e or %g. But anyway, the topic of the question is about %f which we MUST support, no ifs or buts, for better or worse.

Comment: for the value "-0x1.fffffffffffffp+1023" in %a format, your code, using %.12f format, gives "-179769313486231570814527423731704356798070567525844996598917476803157260780028538760589558632766878171540458953514382464234321326889464182768467546703537516986049910576551282076245490090389328944075868508455133942304583236903222948165808559332123348274797826204144723168738177180919299881250404026184124858368.000000000000" (hopefully we're not on twitter), so it's clearly a pity to be forced to use %f. As said by @SteveJessop most of the digit are meaningless.